# Word2Vec for PoS Tagging

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, nltk, gensim, word2vec

May we use Word2Vec for implementing Parts of Speech(PoS) Tagging, or similar other problems of label sequencing. 
I feel we may address this problem from clustering, so I was curious. 
Generally any good lead or discussion would be nice, but a Python example preferably with Gensim learn may be great, as it may have a Word2Vec implementation.

Comment: very broad - try posting it on reddit /machinelearning.

Comment: you can try building a simple classifier using word2vec representation of sequence of words. For example, for a window size of 5, word2vec dimension of 100 -> train a multi-class classifier for 500 dimensional vector to predict the pos-tag of the center word

Comment: Thank you for the same. I will check.